# How to use command `dist` on a sub-project from the root-project?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have a `sbt` project which encapsulates multiple other `sbt` projects (Play microservices). When I want to use `dist` then starting up the `sbt shell`, switching to the sub-project via `project someSubProject` and then running `dist` works fine. But is there a way to do that in one single line like `sbt project someSubProject dist`?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Have you tried `sbt someSubProject/dist`?

Comment: @IvanKurchenko Oh wow, works. Thank you very much.